# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying the execute a java.class

Tags: java

I created the following class located in the MainJPrint.java file

```
import com.XXXXX.pdfPrint.PDFPrint;

public class MainJPrint
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        //System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
        print(".....");
    }   
    public static String print (final String url)
    {
        Object rc = AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction() 
        {
            public Object run()
            {
                 ...
            }
         }
    }
}
```

In the same folder I have a jar archive **jPrint.jar**
I compile the class using the following command

```
>javac -classpath jPrint.jar MainJPrint.java
```

When I'm trying to execute resulted class file, I get this error:

```
>java MainJPrint    

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/XXXXX/pdfPrint/PDFPrint
```

If I uncomment the Hello World line and comment the next line, the program runs fine.

I'm using j2sdk1.4.2 installed at `C:\j2sdk1.4.2`.
I do also have installed other java versions (at C:\Program Files\Java: jre 1.6.0_01, jre 1.6.0_02, j2re1.4.2, jre6, jre7, jdk1.7.0_03)

The PATH variable contains the `C:\j2sdk1.4.2\bin` path, however I think the java.exe is loaded from the upper version, but it shouldn't matter and I can call it like

```
>C:\j2sdk1.4.2\bin\java.exe MainJPrint
```

jPrint.jar is a third party archive and I need to create an applet which exposes a method so I can call it with javascript. I'm not a java developer, I'm having some little troubles and I'm really on an end here.

I tried other options like:

```
>java MainJPrint -cp .
>java MainJPrint -cp jPrint.jar
```

So how can I execute that class file which uses a class located in a separate archive?

Comment: Did you try `java -cp jPrint.jar MainJPrint`? The class argument is usually placed last.

Comment: `java -cp jPring.jar MainJPrint` should have worked.

Comment: Could you provide the whole `MainJPrint.java` content ?

Comment: Why would you still use j2sdk1.4.2?

Comment: @TimBüthe, the third party company recommends to create that applet using this version.

Comment: @TimBüthe, I compiled the class now with 1.7. I got a compilation error (warning), but I fixed with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a class that depends on external JARs, you need to specify all elements of the classpath on the command line.

If you don't specify a classpath, Java automatically uses `.` (the current directory), which is why, if MainJPrint didn't depend on jPrint.jar, your invocation `java MainJPrint` would have worked.

But when you specify `-cp jPrint.jar`, Java does NOT automatically add the current directory to the classpath, which means that it then cannot find MainJPrint.  You need to specify both.  On Mac/*nix, the following invocation should work:

```
java -cp jPrint.jar:. MainJPrint
```

Or on Windows:

```
java -cp jPrint.jar;. MainJPrint
```

Comment: I'm getting Error: Could not find or load main class MainJPrint

Comment: MainJPrint is my class, is not located in the jar, that jar is a third party one

Comment: Are you certain that you're executing that _exact_ command from within a folder that contains both `jPrint.jar` **and** the compiled `MainJPrint.class` files?  You could try reversing the order of the classpath: `java -cp .:jPrint.jar MainJPrint` in case there's some quirk of circumstance going on...

Comment: This is unexpected behavior, and I've just been able to verify the accuracy of my suggestion with several versions of Java on a couple of platforms.  For thoroughness, can you edit your question to include the output of each of the following commands, executed in sequence (assuming you're on Windows based on the > prompt): `dir`, `javac -cp jPrint.jar MainJPrint.java`, `dir`, `java -cp . MainJPrint`, `java -cp jPrint.jar:. MainJPrint`.  It would also be helpful if, instead of an excerpt, you could edit `MainJPrint` to be a minimal example and post its complete code.

Comment: Ah, if you *are* on Windows, then you should actually be separating the entries with a semicolon instead of a colon: `java -cp jPrint.jar;. MainJPrint`.  It's been so many years since I've used Windows that I completely forgot.

Comment: That's killing. Yes, is about ; (Thanks!)